# Logic Pro X - Recording From Multiple Controllers

Tags: software, midi, midi-controller-keyboard, logic-pro

I've figured out that you can connect multiple MIDI keyboards to Logic Pro X so that they each control an individual track by using the MIDI Environment, creating a Physical Input object and attaching each keyboard port to a different track. If I have 5 keyboards and 5 different people controlling each track, it does not allow me to record at the same time. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use different MIDI channels for each track instead? Using the environment here seems like an overkill.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Can you post the solution as your answer? What I mean is, how do you set up different MIDI channels so that they map to each keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the inspector (above the channel strip of the focused track) you'll see a section with the name of the track. Expand it (if it isn't already) and you'll see a MIDI channel section. There you can select a specific channel for the track to listen to, instead of the default "all".

[image: Inspector]

The rest will depend in your devices (keyboards, surface controls, etc). Check on the manual how to send MIDI from your device through a specific channel. Match the channels of the devices with the tracks, and you are done.

You might find another issue (solving it might make your environment approach work):

> If you use the default settings when feeding in two or more MIDI controllers, however, you'll find that all the incoming data gets merged and sent to the selected MIDI track regardless of how the sending devices are set up. Here's how to get around that:
>
> - Under the File menu, select Project Settings.
> - Select the Recording option from the list of settings that pops up.
> - In the MIDI section of the Recording screen, you'll see a tick box labelled 'Auto demix - by channel if multitrack recording'. Check this box.

You can read more on that [here](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/jun12/articles/logic-tech-0612.htm).

Comment: Thanks man...that link really helped. It took me a while to put it all together. The one missing piece that I didn't see right at the end of that article was that you have to "record arm" all tracks that you want to play and record simultaneously. I only realized this when I checked [this site](http://compusition.com/writings/logic-multitrack-midi)...it lists everything in order.

Thanks a mil!